# Testar consultas simultâneas no servidor REST

Tags: rest, testes, asp.net-web-api, owin

Tenho um servidor `REST/WebApi` e queria testar seu desempenho com consultas simultâneas. 
 Meu objetivo é testar, logicamente o desempenho, e também se o mesmo está tratando cada requisição de forma separada, ou seja, cada consulta é tratada por um processo, evitando assim, gargalos nas consultas.

Atualmente estou utilizando o `Postman` para testes simples, vi que ele tem uma ferramenta de teste, porém é paga e não sei se atende meu objetivo.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta para este propósito.

Comment: Uma opção interessante é utilizar cURL (http://curl.haxx.se/). Você pode fazer scritps que chamam o cURL e assim você conseguirá testar conexões simultanenas ao seu REST.

Comment: Realmente é uma ferramenta poderosa, porém, complexa. Queria algo mais prático para realizar esta tarefa. Ou adicione uma resposta de como implementar estes testes.

Comment: Comece procurando por ferramentas de Load Testing. Caso queira algo mais profissional recomendo o serviço do [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/features/vso-cloud-load-testing-vs.aspx).

Comment: Existem duas ferramentas muito boas, JMeter e Apache Benchmarking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem duas ferramentas muito boas, JMeter e Apache Benchmarking.

O Apache Benchmarking é uma ferramenta que vem junto com o Apache httpd(conhecido apenas como apache), é uma ferramenta que roda sobre o terminal.

**AB - Comandos básicos**

```
ab -n 10 -c 10 http://url:porta/path
```

Onde:
*-n* é o número de requisição
*-c* é o numero de concorrência
*-s* é o *timeout* máximo para cada requisição

[image: Resumo da resuição]

Além desse comando básico existem outros parâmetros que pode ajudar nos testes, como **método** que deve ser utilizado na requisição, **resumo** em formato de tabela, dentre outras.

Já o JMeter é bem mais complexo tem uma interface gráfica, foi desenvolvido em swing, por isso será necássario a JVM, nele podemos criar um plano de teste e guardar esse plano, é bem mais complexo em relação ao `ab`

Vale a pena ver a documentação das duas

[AB](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)
[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)